# Idle animation isnt playing properly (roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

what its supposed to look like
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MJNO.png

what it looks like
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewbYR.png

my code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDgOx.png

also the anim prioroty is set to movement

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out this [Article](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/enum/AnimationPriority) about Animation Priority.

Animations have priority queue. Your animation is probably setup as a **Core** priority, meaning other animations have priority before yours. Your image shows that your animation is playing, however the tool animation is prioritized before yours.

To fix this, change the priority of your animation in your Animator to something like **Action**

[image: Example of Animation Priority]